# Does anyone know a decent app to monitor bandwidth usage, ideally from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, network

I'd like to monitor my bandwidth usage on my Macbook pro, and keep logs of it. Ideally, I'd like to view/monitor them via the Terminal. Can anyone recommend me some applications?

EDIT: To clarify, I want to keep a time-series graph of the bandwidth I/O

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41364/how-can-i-use-terminal-to-monitor-a-network-interfaces-total-traffic-in-mb?rq=1

Comment: I already did look at that question. But it wasn't really helpful. I just wanted to keep graphs of bandwidth I/O in a time-series graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) following installation guidelines from [here](http://www.marcomc.com/2011/01/how-to-install-and-configure-ntop-4-on-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/). While it is both a GUI and paid software I liked it a lot during my Windows days and found it to be pretty good on OS X too. The only reason I didn't buy a license was that for my usage it's a want and not a need. :)